# Getting "Server error (Google::Apis::ServerError)" when I try to duplicate sheet google-api-client-0.30.2 in ruby

Tags: ruby, google-sheets-api

Using ***google-api-client***-0.30.2, ***rbenv*** 2.6.2, I get the following error:

> "Server error (Google::Apis::ServerError)"

```
duplicate_sheet_request = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::DuplicateSheetRequest.new
duplicate_sheet_request.source_sheet_id = request["source_sheet_id"].to_i
duplicate_sheet_request.new_sheet_name = request["new_sheet_name"]
duplicate_sheet_request.new_sheet_id = request["source_sheet_id"].to_i
duplicate_sheet_request.insert_sheet_index = request["insert_sheet_index"]

batch_update_spreadsheet_request = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest.new
batch_update_spreadsheet_request.requests = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::Request.new

batch_update_spreadsheet_request_object = [ duplicate_sheet: duplicate_sheet_request ] 
batch_update_spreadsheet_request.requests = batch_update_spreadsheet_request_object 
response = sheets_service.batch_update_spreadsheet(spreadsheet_id, batch_update_spreadsheet_request)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following should work:

```
duplicate_sheet_request = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::DuplicateSheetRequest.new
duplicate_sheet_request.source_sheet_id = request["source_sheet_id"].to_i
duplicate_sheet_request.new_sheet_name = request["new_sheet_name"]
duplicate_sheet_request.new_sheet_id = request["source_sheet_id"].to_i
duplicate_sheet_request.insert_sheet_index = request["insert_sheet_index"]

batch_update_spreadsheet_request = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest.new
request = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::Request.new

request.duplicate_sheet= duplicate_sheet_request
batch_update_spreadsheet_request.requests = [request] 
response = sheets_service.batch_update_spreadsheet(spreadsheet_id, batch_update_spreadsheet_request)
```